# gdb break when entering child process

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I'm having a tough time figuring this one out; I have a program, `iverilog` that executes a `system()` call to invoke another program, `ivl`. I want to debug the second program, `ivl` in gdb, but I can't get gdb to set any breakpoints in the child process when I invoke gdb with the parent process. Here's what the programs look like:

```
//iverilog-main.cpp (Parent process)

int main(){
    //...
    system("ivl arg1 arg2");
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
//ivl-main.cpp (child process)

int main(){
    //...
    //stuff I want to debug
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

.

The gdb commands I'm running are: `gdb iverilog -x cmds.gdb`

```
# cmds.gdb
set args hello.v
set follow-fork-mode child
set breakpoint pending on
break ivl-main.cpp:main
run
```

Unfortunately, gdb doesn't break at `ivl-main.cpp:main`,it just completes without ever breaking; the output I get is:

```
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/iverilog hello.v
[New process 18117]
process 18117 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 2 (process 18117) exited normally]
```

I'm certain `ivl-main.cpp:main` is being called because when I run the `ivl` program in gdb it successfully breaks there.

My thinking is that gdb doesn't recognize ivl-main.cpp as a source file when its running `gdb iverilog`, and it's not setting that breakpoint when it enters the child process which does contain ivl-main.cpp as a source file. So I think if I set the breakpoint for ivl-main.cpp when gdb enters the child process, it should work. The only way I can think of doing this is to manually break at the `system()` call and step into the child process, then set the breakpoint. Is there a more elegant approach that would force gdb to break whenever entering a child process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043074/pause-process-to-allow-time-for-debugger-to-attach) provides one way to achieve what you want.

In theory, `set follow-fork-mode child` should work.

In practice, the `iverilog` is likely itself a shell script that runs (`fork`s) multiple commands, so at every `fork` you will need to decide whether you want to continue debugging the parent or the child. One wrong decision and you've lost control of the process that will eventually execute your program. This very likely explains why it didn't work for you.

Comment: You're right, the `system()` call invoked multiple programs and the one I was interested in wasn't the first, so gdb would follow the first inferior and stop when it was finished. I was able to resolve this by switching to the other inferior when it finished via `inferior 2`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's not that bad, `gdb` has `set schedule-multiple on` which allows running multiple inferior at once, if you use that you don't need to decide which inferior to follow.

Answer (score 13):

Normally GDB only debugs one process at a time- if your program forks then you will debug the parent or the child, but not both simultaneously. By default, GDB continues debugging the parent after a fork, but you can change this behavior if you so desire with the following command:

`set follow-fork-mode child`

Alternately, you can tell GDB to keep both the parent and the child under its control. By default GDB only follows one process, but you can tell it to follow all child processes with this command:

`set detach-on-fork off`

GDB refers to each debugged process as an "inferior". When debugging multiple processes you can examine and interact each process with the "inferiors" command similar to how you would use "threads" to examine or interact with multiple threads.

See more documentation here:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Comment: I have used `set fork-follow-mode child` already yet gdb is still unable to set breakpoints in the "inferior" process.

Comment: Is it possible your call to system is failing and the fork is not happening? All you need to do is set `follow-fork-mode child` and `break main` and GDB should break at EVERY invocation of a "main" function it encounters. You don't even need to set the specific source code file you want to break at (even files that haven't been loaded yet).

Comment: gdb 8.0-20.fc26 recognizes follow-fork-mode, not fork-follow-mode.