# How to gdb from main() of app2 triggered by app1?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Provided app2 is triggered by app1 in which there is something like system("./app2"). app1 also does a lot of preparation such as creating dirs, files, configuration... for app2 running.

How can I gdb app2 from the first line of its main()?

What I tried as below doesn't work.

```
gdb app2
  b main
  shell ./app1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `system("./app2");`

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1. If `app1` doesn't close `stdin, stdout, stderr`, you could modify `app1` to do this instead: `system("gdb ./app2")
2. You could modify `app2` to *wait* for debugger to be attached, as e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617) shows. Then run `app1`, and use `gdb -p $child_pid` from another window.
3. If `app1` doesn't fork any children prior to `app2`, you could use `(gdb) set follow-fork child` and have GDB automatically start debugging `app2` after `app1` forks it.