# Debug using gdb where the program takes input from another program

Tags: gdb

I need to debug a program that feeds on the output of another program. Hence, writing the output of the 'feeder' into a file, and piping that to the 'reader' doesn't work.

Normal run:

```
# feeder | ./reader
```

This is NOT an option here:

```
# feeder > data
# gdb ./reader
(gdb) run < data
```

Comment: *Why* is it NOT an option?

Comment: Because the output of feeder is not continuous. A dump to file, pipe from file would simply push all data at once.

Comment: Wonder why the downvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `reader` pause and wait for GDB to attach, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617).

Then run:

```
feeder | ./reader
```

in one terminal, and `gdb -p $(pgrep reader)` in another terminal.

Once gdb is attached, let the `reader` proceed, and debug it normally.

**Update:**

Now that you've clarified your constraint, another way is to use named pipe:

```
mknod /tmp/.pipe p
feeder > /tmp/.pipe
gdb reader
(gdb) run < /tmp/.pipe
```

Comment: Not the most elegant way, but a well placed sleep could work indeed.

Comment: @Bgs I think your question is under-specified, but you may be able to use a named pipe. Answer updated.