# Debug using gdb the initial startup of a linux daemon

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, service, gdb

I want to debug the very initial startup of a daemon started as a service under linux (centos 7).

My service is started as:  "service mydaemon start"

I know about attaching gdb to a running process, but, unfortunately that technique is too slow, the initial execution of mydaemon is important.

mydaemon is written in C++ and full debug info is available.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Answer (score 3):

> unfortunately that technique is too slow

There are two general solutions to this problem.

The first one is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617): you make your target executable *wait* for GDB to attach (this requires building a special version of the daemon).

The second is to "wrap" your daemon in gdbserver (as root):

```
mv mydaemon mydaemon.exe
echo > mydaemon <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
exec gdbserver :1234 /path/to/mydaemon.exe "$@"
EOF
chmod +x mydaemon
```

Now execute `service mydaemon start`, and your process will be stopped by gdbserver and will wait for connection from GDB.

```
gdb /path/to/mydaemon.exe
(gdb) target remote :1234
# You should now be looking at the mydaemon process stopped in `_start`.
```

At that point you can set beakpoints, and use `continue` or `next` or `step` as appropriate.

Comment: great answer.    I should have thought of the second one!   like your Mammut icon.    thanks!