# How to automatically attach to GDB on startup

Tags: c++, gdb

We have a C++ executable that will be executed by another Java program. I want to debug this C++ executable, but by the time I attach GDB to its PID, the startup code that I want to debug has already executed.

Instead of attaching GDB to the process, I want the process to automatically attach itself to GDB when it starts. How can I achieve this?

If you know how to achieve this in CLion, clangd+VSCode, or Qt Creator, please explain the steps for each.

Comment: Dup maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147567/4641116

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48455259/50617 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617 may be useful as well.