# Debug c/c++ application loaded into memory by python script, with GDB

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb

I'm using a python script which ultimately starts another C++ executable which in turn loads several other applications into memory for execution, along with other .so shared libraries using `dlopen`.

What GDB command should I be using to debug(run backtrace etc.) these dynamically loaded executables and libraries ?

I tried running it as `gdb --args python3 py-script arg1 arg2 arg3...` but after execution I tried the following two commands for debugging.

`bt -full`

`thread apply all bt`

but both of them throw the error `No stack`.

Comment: dynamically loading executables is _probably_ not what you are actually doing. This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian that worked ! I was doing it wrong initially.